# Why would we use bitwise operators between 2 numbers?

Tags: java, bitwise-operators

I don't understand, given the information below, why you would ever want to evaluate, for example, 2 hex integers with the `&` operator. I understand the inversion pattern explained below, and I can calculate it myself, but it's hard to deduce *why* (from posts I see on the internet). What is the real world scenario that might give me insight here?

```
  0xff00 & 0xf0f0 is 0xf000
  0xff00 ^ 0xf0f0 is 0x0ff0
  0xff00 | 0xf0f0 is 0xfff0
For &, the result value is the bitwise AND of the operand values.
For ^, the result value is the bitwise exclusive OR of the operand values.
For |, the result value is the bitwise inclusive OR of the operand values.
```

In my own head, I currently think of it like this:

```
if ( 65280 & 61680 )  // evaluates to 61440, not boolean?
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

These kinds of operators are used for lots of things, but these days in higher level languages they are most commonly used with flags. It's a holdover from lower level languages like C, in which memory allocation and deallocation is not always trivial, and which was developed at a time where hardware resources were scarce.

Let's say there are 3 possible flags for some operation, and they can be provided in any given combination.  A quick, easy, and efficient way to supply a flag is to assign each flag to a bit in an integer.

```
public static final int FLAG_1 = 1;       // 00000001
public static final int FLAG_2 = 1 << 1;  // 00000010
public static final int FLAG_3 = 1 << 2;  // 00000100
```

Then to send multiple flags, I can use the bitwise or "|" operator.

```
someFunc(FLAG_1 | FLAG_3).
```

To read the flags that are passed, I can use the bitwise & operator.

```
public void someFunc(int flags) {
    if ((flags & FLAG_1) == FLAG_1 /*Or (flags & FLAG_1) != 0 */) { 
      // Passed in flag 1.
    }
}
```

There are other ways that this can be done, but this is very efficient, easy to read, and results in zero object allocations on the heap. If you think of other ways you'd accomplish this in Java, let's say with an array or collection of enums/ints, or with each flag being a separate method parameter, it's clear why this pattern is used instead.

Comment: Isn't there a precedence problem with your example?

Comment: Thank you!  I almost understand I think.  The `FLAG_1 == FLAG_1` thing is still confusing.  Thinking about it...     Maybe ill try to write some code with your sample.

Comment: @djangofan I updated it, thanks to Eric's suggestion, I think you'll find it much more clear now.

Comment: Ahh,  now I understand.  Thank you sooooo much!

Comment: Also `1 << 2` should be `00000100`. ;)

Comment: When I was typing that out I knew there was no way I'd get it right the first time.

Comment: Still, it's a very nice example. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think that if you need to implement a small array of `boolean`, it could be a good idea to represent it as an `int` or `long`, with each bit representing one array element:

- if there is a huge number of those arrays, so that memory usage is a concern; or
- if you are doing a huge number of calculations.

In that case, you'd use the shift operators and `&`, `|`, `&=`, `|=`, or `^=` to test, clear, set, or flip elements of the array.  (Note also that this can be used on multiple elements of array in parallel.)

It's rare that this case comes up.  For readability, it's much better to use a regular `array` or `ArrayList`.  However, I've had both use cases come up at least once.  One was writing a Sudoku solver using a brute-force backtracking algorithm; I don't remember the details, but I think I used 9 bits of an `int` to represent whether the cells in a row, column, or square were occupied.  If I recall correctly, some of my code tested multiple cells simultaneously, which I could do with one `&` operator.  Since solving by backtracking can involve a huge number of combinations, I believe that using this mechanism made a noticeable difference in the running time.  The other case involved a table of items that kept information on whether items had certain properties.  The number of properties was relatively small (between 10 and 20), but the number of items could run into the tens of millions.  A `Set` would have been the natural choice for representing the set of properties, but with the huge number of `HashSet`s I'd need to keep, memory was a concern.

I wouldn't recommend this unless there is a big difference in memory or time.  It smacks of "trickiness", and I prefer straightforward code that expresses what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

For a very basic example in an if-statement :

```
if ( (65280 & 1) == 0 ){
  // 65280 is even!
}
```

- `x & 1` is `0` if `x` is even
- `x & 1` is `1` if `x` is odd

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at some source code written in Java (it was originally ported from C):

```
int dest = y * width + (x & 0xfffc);
```

Took me a while to realize what it means:

0xfffc is 65532 or 1111111111111100

dest is the offset in an array of size 65536.

So what does the expression above actually say?

I think it says:

```
int dest = y * width + (x<=65532?x:65532);
```